com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonNull
     var retrofitResponse: RetrofitResponse<APIResponse<User>>? = null
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            retrofitResponse = try {
                val response = BindRetrofitWithService.getServiceInstance(
                    needCustomTimeOut = Config.isChinaBuild(appContext)
                ).registerUser(body, data)
                RetrofitResponse(true, response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                RetrofitResponse(false, e.getAPIError())
            }
        }
        return retrofitResponse!!

 fun getServiceInstance(needCustomTimeOut: Boolean = false): APIServices {
        if (GeneralUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return getRetrofit(needCustomTimeOut).create(APIServices::class.java)
        } else {
            throw NoNetworkException()
        }
    }

 fun getRetrofit(needCustomTimeOut: Boolean = false): Retrofit {

        return getRetrofitObject(
            null, if (needCustomTimeOut) {
                CHINA_FILE_UPLOAD_CONNECT_TIME_OUT
            } else {
                CONNECT_TIME_OUT
            }else {
                WRITE_TIME_OUT
            }
        )
    }


    /**
     * Custom Retrofit instance creation
     */
    private fun getRetrofitObject(
        headers: HashMap<String, String>?,
        connectionTimeOut: Long,
        readTimeOut: Long,
        writeTimeOut: Long
    ): Retrofit {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        //okHttpClient.addInterceptor(MockInterceptor())
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
            //if(GeneralUtils.isNetworkAvailable()){
            val original = chain.request()
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            if (headers != null && headers.size > 0) {
                for ((key, value) in headers) {
                    requestBuilder.addHeader(key, value)
                }
            }
            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            return@addInterceptor chain.proceed(request)

            /*}else{
                throw NoNetworkException()
            }*/
        }
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(connectionTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(readTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(writeTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.getRetrofitBaseUrl(UCHContext.getAppContext()))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .client(okHttpClient.build())
            .build()
    }

user model class
 @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_NOTE)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_NOTE)
    @Nullable
    public String note = null;

    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_TITLE)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_TITLE_VAL)
    @Nullable
    public String titled = null;
    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_ADDRESSES)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_ADDRESSES)
    @Nullable
    public JsonObject addresses= new JsonObject();


Note :
here sometimes "addresses":null come this scenario following error come
#com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonNull; at path
$.data.addresses
#responseCode= 1208, responseCodeMessage= Api Failure, userMessage= Something went wrong, please try again.
how solve this issue  ? i tried custom or default Gson class also no use

